# Are dead or unconscious enemies part of the Neural Network?

Tags: xcom-chimera-squad

Verge's **Crowdsource** ability grants the following passive:

> Verge gains +5 Aim and +10 Critical Chance for each enemy in the Neutral Network.

This seems like a nice ability, but in my experience you normally won't have more than 2 living enemies in the neural network. Due to this the bonus it normally gives (at least to Aim) will be fairly small. On the other hand, if dead or unconscious enemies are still considered to be part of the Neural Network, then that's a different story entirely. So before I decide which ability I want to grab for this promotion, it would be nice to know which enemies will actually grant the bonus. I'm playing on Ironman, so I can't just do a save and reload to figure this out without locking myself into one of the abilities first.

[image: Verge Crowdsource]

Are dead or unconscious enemies part of the Neural Network for the purposes of the Crowdsource bonus?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unconscious enemies still count as part of your Neural Network but dead enemies will lose their tether.

Comment: Do these carry over from previous encounters? E.g. when doing: `Breach --> 1 knocked unconscious --> next Breach`, does the bonus apply after the second breach?

Comment: @Nijin22 - no, does not last between encounters, even if they're still unconscious.

Comment: Yeah, I can confirm this.